# Where can fuel consumption data by aircraft type and route be found?

Tags: datasets, flight-data-monitoring

I am interested in building a data analytics platform for fuel consumption by aircraft type and route. I imagine this kind of information is readily available to airlines thanks to ACARS data. I need the data to build CO<sub>2</sub> emissions models.

Are they any freely-available datasets or do I need to get this information from an airline directly?

Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as this meets previously established criteria of "shopping" for a source of something.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an answer to my own question. However, hopefully, someone will be able to expand further on this.

- For US Airlines, the [bureau of transportation statistics](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/fuel.asp) is a reliable source. And the data is free!